# Is there a way to get angular $http params to match the nodejs querystring format? Or to get node querystring to consume the angular format?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, query-string, angular-http

The nodejs querystring format expects parameters as follows:

```
foo[bar]=abc --> {foo:{bar:"abc"}}
```

The angular $http module (and anything depending on it, like ngresource), translate params as follows

```
{foo:{bar:"abc"}} --> foo={bar:"abc"}
```

and then urlencodes the JSON above.

Is there any way to pass params to `$http` so that it puts the output as `foo[bar]=abc` and not `foo={bar:"abc"}`?

BTW, setting params as `{"foo[bar]":"abc"}` *does* work, but it is very ugly.

Conversely, is there any way to get node querystring to consume the urlencoded version of `foo={bar:"abc"}` that angular creates and present it to the node side as `{foo:{bar:"abc"}}`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a nodejs user, but nodejs should almost certainly expect 'real' JSON in an AJAX request. If it's expecting

```
{"foo[bar]":"abc"}
```

I think something be setup incorrectly.

However, if indeed you to transform your request for all requests you could configure $http.

In the config method of your app configure $http using $httpProvider as shown below:

```
angular.module('myModule', []);
       .config($httpProvider, function($httpProvider) {
          $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data) {
            return transformMyData(data);
          };
       });
```

And then just write the function transformMyData(...) to transform it into the format you would like.

Comment: For whatever reason, I think that is how nodejs querystring expects the query to be formatted. I will add the tags for it to the question to see if any of the node gurus have any other suggestions. Your idea to add a request transform to flip `{foo:{bar:"abc"}}` to `{"foo[bar]":"abc"}` is nice and elegant. I don't terribly mind the second version, but having that in my service or controller is so twisted that it is almost guaranteed to cause me to make mistakes.